# Koszul exterior connections

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, exterior-algebra

Let $(E,M)$ be a vector bundle over a riemannian manifold $M$ which is a module for the exterior forms of $M$. I define a Koszul exterior connection as an operator $\nabla$ such that:
$$
\nabla : E \rightarrow \Lambda^* (TM)\otimes_{{\cal C}^{\infty}(M)} E
$$
$$
\nabla_{\alpha} f.s= df^* (\alpha) \wedge s + f.\nabla_{\alpha}s
$$
$\alpha$ is an exterior form, $f$ is a smooth function and $s$ is a section of $E$.
Can we define a notion of curvature for such a connection?

Comment: How do you pull back an exterior form by a function??

Comment: It is not the pullback, it is the contraction of the form by the dual vector of df.

Comment: What's the problem in taking the usual definition as the square of the connection?

Comment: We have to define the Lie brackets of two exterior forms for the curvature by the Gerstenhaber algebras.